# Specifying multiple one-to-many relationships between tables in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have two tables: Teams and Matches

The Teams table is made up as follows [Team ID, Team Name]
The Matches table is made up as follows [Match ID, Home Team, Away Team, Result]

Home Team and Away Team are foreign keys from the Teams table therefore there are two one-to-many relationships defined between the Teams and Matches table.

I'm know how to specify single relationships between two tables but how can I specify multiple relationships between two tables? Is it the same process?

How can these relationships be specified in Hibernate?

Comment: You mean specify that "Home Team" and "Away Team" are many-to-one relationships? See the Hibernate docs for many-to-one mapping: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch08.html#assoc-unidirectional-m21

Comment: Right, so specifying multiple relationships between two tables is the same process as specifying a single relationship?

Comment: Absolutely - you can set up as many many-to-one relationships as makes sense; in this case, each "team" on a Match would be one many-to-one relationship.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have a uni-directional mapping between Teams and Matches as follows:

**In Matches Class:**

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "home_team_id", referencedColumnName = "team_id")
private Team homeTeam;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "away_team_id", referencedColumnName = "team_id")
private Team awayTeam;
```

If you need a **bi-directional relationship** you can add the following :

**In Teams Class :**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "homeTeam")
private Set<Matches> homeMatches;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "awayTeam")
private Set<Matches> awayMatches;
```